# Azure Function App not working after changing storage account connection string

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I tried to update the storage account connection string in the AzureWebJobsStorage application setting of my function app but after updating, all the functions started giving 401 Unauthorized in the response even though the Inbound and Outbound IP address of the function app are whitelisted in the storage account.

The only function that works is the one which has AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous in the code.

I have tried to restart the function app and also redeployed it from the azure pipelines but nothing seems to work. I am really stuck and can't figure out what am I missing here. I would be really thankful if someone could help me.

Comment: By default function keys are stored in storage account and the function host uses the `AzureWebJobsStorage` connectionstring to get/create these keys. I imagine the function host regenarated new keys. could you confirm that ?

Comment: Can you please tell how I can decrypt the function keys and check. I could not find how to decrypt those keys.

Answer (score 1):

To change the storage account from existing to new in Azure Function App, you need to change the Application settings under Configuration that contains Storage Connection Strings of the Function App in Azure Portal.

> Depending on the function this may be the [AzureWebJobsStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage) and [WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentazurefileconnectionstring) strings.

**One of the workarounds I did to get the successful result after changing the storage account is**:

1. Created the Azure Function (.NET 6 - HTTP Trigger) in the Portal and run the function:

[image]

2. Next, Changed the Storage Account Name and Key Value in the App Settings [`AzureWebJobsStorage` and `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING`] in the Azure Function App Configuration from the Portal.
3. Got the ***401 Unauthorized*** when testing the function app immediately.
4. Then I click on **Restart** of the Azure Function App > Overview section - it worked well:

**Result**:

[image]

#### Updated Answer:

If you're still getting the issue because of Authorization keys in the Function App URL, then try this setting:

[image: RenewFunctionKeyValue]

- Go to your Function App in the Azure Portal > Functions > your Function > Function Keys > Renew Key Value
- Restart the Function immediately after the key is renewed successfully.
- Then, Run the Function.

> Can you please tell how I can decrypt and check the function key values in azure-webjobs-secrets because I think the function keys have already been regenerated.

You can get the Function Keys from this Path in the Portal:
[image]

To decrypt the same keys located in the Storage Account > Containers > azure-webjobs-secrets > host.json file, there is a property from that host.json file called as decryptionKeyId which is used to decrypt the encrypted values.

[image]

Please refer to [Decrypt the key from inside a function app](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/a4b49641-00f8-4f2a-a4ea-187b87b36e06/decrypt-the-machine-key-from-inside-a-function-app?forum=AzureFunctions) for practical workaround.

Comment: I tried restarting the function app, even redeploying it but it didn't work for me. I think it is related to the azure function authorization.

Comment: Hello @Palak, could you please check the updated answer!

Comment: Can you please tell how I can decrypt and check the function key values in azure-webjobs-secrets because I think the function keys have already been regenerated.

Comment: @Palak, Updated the answer with proper information regarding function keys.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was deleting the `host.json` file from `azure-webjobs-secrets/{your-function-name}` blob container in the function storage account (AzureWebJobsStorage) and restarting the function app.

I got the idea when troubleshooting this via Azure Portal > Diagnose and solve problems > Configuration and Management > Function Keys Operations:

> Since Azure Functions support API Key Authorization,
> a function key or host key change may cause function authentication error.
> In this case, the customer needs to manually update the API Keys for their clients.
>
> A key change events may be triggered by
>
> 1. A customer revokes/renews function keys or host keys in Portal/Azure CLI
> 2. A customer makes a PUT/POST/DELETE request on a Key Management API
> 3. A customer removes the webjobs secret files from the function app's file system or azure-webjobs-secrets blob storage
> 4. A customer changes MACHINEKEY_DecryptionKey app setting
> 5. A customer uses keyvault to store the function keys and change the value of it.
> 6. The ASP.NET Core DataProtection service decides a function key or host key is staled and needs to be regenerated
>
> Please note that the Azure Functions Keys can also be removed if the Storage account has a Blob Lifecycle Management Policy enabled.